# Initializing a LookupMap with near-sdk-rust

Tags: rust, webassembly, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I am currently developing a contract where I want to make use of a LookupMap, however it's not clear to me how to initialize it. Here is the code:

```rust
// Just a structyre
pub struct Gift {
    url: String,
    n_tokens_required: usize,
    current_tokens: usize,
}

// Main contract code
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct Voting { // TODO: Rename this class
    pub gifts: LookupMap<String, Vector<Gift>>,
    pub contract_owner: String,
}

impl Default for Voting {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Voting {gifts: LookupMap::new(), contract_owner: env::current_account_id()}
    }
}
```

So I want the *gifts* attribute of my contract to be a LookupMap with the signature `LookupMap<String, Vector<Gift>>`. How can I initialize it on my  default function implementation?

When I try to do `LookupMap::new()`, it says that I need a parameter *key_prefix*, with the trait IntoStorageKey, however it's not clear to me what this parameter actually is.

Could anyone help me understand this better?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find your answer on this page https://www.near-sdk.io/contract-structure/collections